# Designing an ASP.NET application handling and searching MS Office documents

Tags: elasticsearch, webforms, sql-server-2012, full-text-search, asp.net-4.5

I'm currently designing a new web application which will deal with a lot of MS Office documents.

One of the requirements is the ability to search not only in the columns of my SQL Server database tables, but also in the documents that get uploaded into the web application on the tune of roughly 50-200 documents per day. My solution should be able to search both the document **content**, as well as the **metadata** of the Office documents (creator etc.)

I was wondering if anyone has had practical experience with such a solution, and could help me design it.

My first idea was to use SQL Server 2012's `FILETABLE` approach: define a common directory for the documents, surface that as a `FILETABLE` in a SQL Server table, and put a SQL Server Fulltext Catalog on top of that. I'm pretty confident this would allow me to search the files by their name, and also their content (using fulltext search) - but what about the **metadata**? I can't seem to find anything much on that ....

Also: does anyone have any hands-on, practical experience in terms of **performance** of such a solution? I have a hard time judging just how much the Win32 I/O to store new documents into that `FILETABLE` folder will affect performance. What about fulltext search on a `FILETABLE` based set of MS Office documents? Any experiences there?

A second idea was to use some kind of a dedicated fulltext search system, like ElasticSearch - any comments on that? Does ES support indexing and searching MS Office documents, **including** the metadata? Or does it index the *contents* of the documents only?

Any ideas and pointers - and *especially* hands-on, real-life experiences - would be most welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your second idea, Elasticsearch supports indexing MS Office documents through the [mapper attachments plugin](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments) which is powered by [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/), and thus supports all kinds of [MS Office document formats](http://tika.apache.org/1.11/formats.html#Microsoft_Office_document_formats). That plugin not only indexes the file content but also the metadata as you require, i.e. `date`, `title`, `author`, `content type`, etc.

So the idea is to create an index and a mapping type with a field having the `attachment` type and all the metadata fields you want to index and search as well.

```
PUT /test_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "test_type": {
      "properties": {
        "my_attachment": {
          "type": "attachment",
          "fields": {
            "content": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "no"
            },
            "title": {
              "type": "string",
              "store": "yes"
            },
            "date": {
              "type": "date",
              "store": "yes"
            },
            "author": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "myAnalyzer"
            },
            "keywords": {
              "type": "string",
              "store": "yes"
            },
            "content_type": {
              "type": "string",
              "store": "yes"
            },
            "content_length": {
              "type": "integer",
              "store": "yes"
            },
            "language": {
              "type": "string",
              "store": "yes"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can search any of those fields, namely the file content itself as well as any metadata fields.

If you want to make a dry run of that plugin, it also offers [a standalone tool](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments#stand-alone-runner) that you can run to see what would be extracted from your documents, and hence what can be searched from them.

Comment: have you been able to try this out?

Comment: Apparently, you've [chosen the other way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993405/sql-server-2012-fulltext-search-on-top-of-a-filetable-pdf-not-being-searched) :)

Comment: Haven't decided yet - still evaluating and trying :-) Thanks.